# How to do server side pagination in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pagination

I have following code and I am very new to Angular. I want to apply pagination is the  get response which are over 2500+ rows. Here I am pulling up the data from a local MySQL instance.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <!-- index.php !-->  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title></title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  

                <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="usercontroller" ng-init="displayData()"> 
                <h1><span style="color: red">TOTAL COUNT: </span>{{ (names | filter:isQuestionInRange).length }}</h1> 
                       <p>FIlter by = <input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
                       <br />
                       <p>LIMIT TO = <input type="text" ng-model="test1"></p>
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th>First Name</th>  
                               <th>Last Name</th>
                               <th>image</th>  
                          </tr>  
                          <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test | limitTo:test1">  
                               <td>{{x.id}}</td>  
                               <td>{{x.last_name}}</td>  
                               <td>{{x.first_name}}</td> 
                          </tr>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);  
 app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http){  

      $scope.displayData = function(){  
           $http.get("../webui/echo-from-php.php")  
           .success(function(data){  
                $scope.names = data;  
           });  
      }  
 });  
 </script>




AND my php file is as follows where I a running query. I dint have much text to write over here but as I am required to I am gonna elaborate it. I need to run this data in front end such that it loads faster also looks good via pagination. I saw many examples but couldn't figure out how to get the data with request.



<?php  
 //select.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root123", "root", "customerdb");  
 $output = array();  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM customers";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can write a loading function which will load data from B.E (back-end) using `$http` or `$resource`, the data should be saved in a JSON structure, 
the same JSON structure must be used to display in HTML with Angular scope-bound variables, which means you have to use same variable in your `ng-repeat` to iterate over and render table or div-sets.
thats the rendering part, 
now to implement paginated data , maintain 2 state variable

1. cursor position
2. page size,

these two variable must be sent to B.E when you make call to fetch data, something like `../webui/echo-from-php.php?cP=101&pS=100` , 
this query should essentially fetch 100(pS) rows only starting from row #101 (cP) - you can use `mysql_fetch_array` with limit clause to achieve that.

And then you controller function must also accept two arguments for cP and pS,

now for pagination control you can use `dir-Pagination` (https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination), and use its page change event handler (`on-page-change`) to call your controller data load function in which dir-pagination will pass right values of cP and pS.

since you mentioned you are new to Angular, I can understand how over-whelming it may be sounding, but take it step by step, you will soon start grasping it and implement it further.

All the best